# Web Api Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-identity

I'm just trying to authentication a user with Asp.Identity in DelegatingHandler.

Like this code above:

```
public class TokenAuthentication : DelegatingHandler {
        private readonly AuthenticationIdentityManager _identityManager;

        public TokenAuthentication() {
            _identityManager = new AuthenticationIdentityManager(new IdentityStore(new NFeDb()));
        }

        private Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager {
            get {
                return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
            if (request.Headers.Contains("X-TokenCliente")) {
                var tokenCliente = request.Headers.GetValues("X-TokenCliente").First();
                var s = _identityManager.Authentication.SignIn(this.AuthenticationManager, tokenCliente, false);
                if (s.Success) {
                    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                }
            }

            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
```

But, at my controller with the Authorize notation:

```
[Authorize]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get() {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

I recive 302 status e redirected to Login page. Is possible to authenticate in DelegatingHandler?

**UPDATE:** I don't know if I need to use OwinMiddleware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 302 redirection is probably from Cookie middleware.

If you are going to use token authentication, you'd better use the OWIN bearer token middleware.

Please check out: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-the-spa-template-for-vs2013-rc/

The blog covers how to use bearer token in web api and how to work side by side with cookie middleware.